# Position of i class is affected by another class

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, font-awesome

I want to add a font awesome icon next to user comments. So it would look like this:
[image]

This is what it looks like with just html and css together, with nothing commented out/deleted.

html:

```
    <div class="commentsWindow">
        <div class="output" id="output">
            <h6 class="username">The Spider</h6>
            <h6 class="date">2 hours ago</h6>
            <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v icon" id="myicon"></i>
            <p class="comments">People like commenting </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
.output {
    margin: 30px 0px 0px 50px;
    width: 550px;
}

.output h6,
output i {
    display: inline-block;
}

.output .username {
    margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.output .date {
    color: #193B59;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.icon {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
}

.output p {
    font-size: 14px;
    word-break: break-word;
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```

Okay now, I first comment this out to allow some code to take effect in js:
Everything between the curly braces is commented out.

```
    <div class="commentsWindow">
        <div class="output" id="output">
            {{!-- <h6 class="username">The Spider</h6>
            <h6 class="date">2 hours ago</h6>
            <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v icon" id="myicon"></i>
            <p class="comments">People like commenting </p> --}}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now over to my js file:
This is code I use to output user comments:

js:

```
function loadcomments() {
    fetch('http://localhost:5502' + '/get_messages')
        .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
                console.log('success')
                console.log(response);
            } else {
                console.log('failure')
            }
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function(data) {

            io.emit("new_message", data)
            io.on("new_message", function(data) {
                console.log("Server says", data);
                output.innerHTML = '';
                data.forEach(function(user) {

                    var newUser = document.createElement("div");
                    var newName = document.createElement("h6");
                    var newDate = document.createElement("h6");
                    var newMessage = document.createElement("p");
                    var newIcon = document.createElement("i");

                    newUser.className = 'output';
                    newName.className = 'username';
                    newDate.className = 'date';
                    newIcon.setAttribute("class", "fas fa-ellipsis-v icon");
                    newMessage.className = 'comments';

                    var display_username = document.createTextNode(user.username);
                    var display_date = document.createTextNode(user.date);
                    var display_comments = document.createTextNode(user.comments);

                    newName.appendChild(display_username);
                    newDate.appendChild(display_date);
                    newMessage.appendChild(display_comments);

                    newUser.appendChild(newName);
                    newUser.appendChild(newDate);
                    newUser.appendChild(newMessage);
                    newUser.appendChild(newIcon);
                    output.appendChild(newUser);

                    console.log(data);

                }).catch(function(error) {
                    console.log(error)

                })
```

Now this is the output I get:
[image]

Here's the before and after pics next to each other:

Just html and css:
[image]

Html, css, and js:
[image]

This font awesome icon is supposed to be inline with username and date as specified in CSS, but that goes out the window once I use js.

It looks like the p class is also affecting my i class as well Don't know why.

In the js code, here's the specific part to look at, with regards to the i class and perhaps also the p class:

js:

```
  var newUser = document.createElement("div");
                    var newName = document.createElement("h6");
                    var newDate = document.createElement("h6");
                    var newMessage = document.createElement("p");
                    var newIcon = document.createElement("i");

                    newUser.className = 'output';
                    newName.className = 'username';
                    newDate.className = 'date';
                    newIcon.setAttribute("class", "fas fa-ellipsis-v icon");
                    newMessage.className = 'comments';

                    var display_username = document.createTextNode(user.username);
                    var display_date = document.createTextNode(user.date);
                    var display_comments = document.createTextNode(user.comments);

                    newName.appendChild(display_username);
                    newDate.appendChild(display_date);
                    newMessage.appendChild(display_comments);

                    newUser.appendChild(newName);
                    newUser.appendChild(newDate);
                    newUser.appendChild(newMessage);
                    newUser.appendChild(newIcon);
                    output.appendChild(newUser);
```

I hope I've made this question clear enough. Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance. I'm still new to this as well. Any help is appreciated.

Note: This question was edited from a previous one to better illustrate the problem, so some comments are from the original question.

Comment: You want to set the class of the font awesome icon ? I suggest you to use the `setAttribute` function. Try to replace `newIcon.className = 'icon';` with `newIcon.setAttribute("class", "fas fa-example icon");`.

Comment: I'm not sure the issue is where you think it is. What does your console say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this like this:

1. I suggest putting your icon inside h6 element, that will be make it inline with that row. `newDate.appendChild(newIcon);`
2. As the icon is floating you need to expend that parent element (adjust this to suit your needs, use `px` or `%`):

   .date{
   width: 50%;
   }

```js
var newUser = document.createElement("div");
var newName = document.createElement("h6");
var newDate = document.createElement("h6");
var newMessage = document.createElement("p");
var newIcon = document.createElement("i");

newUser.className = 'output';
newName.className = 'username';
newDate.className = 'date';
newIcon.setAttribute("class", "fa fa-address-book icon");
newMessage.className = 'comments';

var display_username = document.createTextNode("test user");
var display_date = document.createTextNode("2020");
var display_comments = document.createTextNode("test comment");

newName.appendChild(display_username);
newDate.appendChild(display_date);
newMessage.appendChild(display_comments);

newUser.appendChild(newName);
newUser.appendChild(newDate);
newDate.appendChild(newIcon);
newUser.appendChild(newMessage);
output.appendChild(newUser);
```

```css
.output {
  margin: 30px 0px 0px 50px;
  width: 350px;
}

.output h6,
output i {
  display: inline-block;
}

.output .username {
  margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.output .date {
  color: #193B59;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.date{
width: 50%;
}

.icon {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
}

.output p {
  font-size: 14px;
  word-break: break-word;
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="commentsWindow">
  <div class="output" id="output">

  </div>
</div>
```

Also take note that you where appending child icon after you already appended message and that pushed icon below, you can try just to append icon before massage (rearrange order of `appendChild`) and see if that works for you (h6 element has margin of 32px, so do that to icon also to make it "inline"):

```js
var newUser = document.createElement("div");
var newName = document.createElement("h6");
var newDate = document.createElement("h6");
var newMessage = document.createElement("p");
var newIcon = document.createElement("i");

newUser.className = 'output';
newName.className = 'username';
newDate.className = 'date';
newIcon.setAttribute("class", "fa fa-address-book icon");
newMessage.className = 'comments';

var display_username = document.createTextNode("test user");
var display_date = document.createTextNode("2020");
var display_comments = document.createTextNode("test comment");

newName.appendChild(display_username);
newDate.appendChild(display_date);
newMessage.appendChild(display_comments);

newUser.appendChild(newName);
newUser.appendChild(newDate);
newUser.appendChild(newIcon);
newUser.appendChild(newMessage);
output.appendChild(newUser);
```

```css
.output {
  margin: 30px 0px 0px 50px;
  width: 350px;
}

.output h6,
output i {
  display: inline-block;
}

.output .username {
  margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.output .date {
  color: #193B59;
  font-size: 14px;
}


.icon {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 32px;
}

.output p {
  font-size: 14px;
  word-break: break-word;
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="commentsWindow">
  <div class="output" id="output">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, man. Problem solved. Did a few adjustments as well on Icon, using 
    transform: translateX(...px);
Really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the issue is where you think it is; but I think this might be what you are after?

Change;

`newIcon.className = 'icon';`

to be;

`newIcon.className = 'fas fa-ellipsis-v icon';`

I'm presuming the elements are being made, but your FontAwesome icon isn't appearing because no where in your code that is creating the element are the appropriate FontAwesome classes being assigned.

Looking at your code, you're just creating an element like so;

`<i class="icon"></i>`

Making the change I propose you will now create an element like so;

`<i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v icon"></i>`

**EDIT after your EDIT:** review your CSS where you have;

```
.output h6,
output i {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I think you mean;

```
.output h6,
.output i {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

As per my comments, [here is a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/94p8yfvz/) I put together. It appears that your CSS for `.output .date {...}` may also be throwing things out of line. So you could add `margin: 0px` to it like so;

```
.output .date {
    color: #193B59;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0px; /** remove this and watch it go out of line **/
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to call it or apply the classes? ``.className`` does not call it, it applies the classes... So I'm not sure what you mean. Are you able to put together a working demo on JSFiddle or CodePen so I can take a look and maybe figure out what is wrong?

Comment: I've made a whole new edit above with question change. I think this time around, I've made my question and illustration much clearer. I think you'll be able to understand now.

Having trouble with the demo thing, but please have a look above. I suggest you delete your answers comments since I've changed the question and everything.

Comment: @Samora.M - okay, your issue isn't the JavaScript. Your issue is the CSS. As far as ``.output .date {..}`` is concerned, you have Margins being applied that throw stuff out of whack. It's hard to diagnose; but you should inspect the CSS related to ``Modex`` rather than ``The Spider`` example if this makes sense?

Comment: Here is a fiddle to show you, I've commented inside ``.output .date {..}`` to show you. If you comment the line or remove where I added ``margin: 0px`` you will see it goes a bit weird - https://jsfiddle.net/fqg0nu58/

Comment: @Samora.M - You should put together a JSFiddle, CodePen or a Snippet rather than screenshotting, as people can diagnose or troubleshoot your issues better. We can't inspect screenshots to see what is happening or why.

Comment: Also, you didn't need to ``.setAttribute`` - just doing ``newIcon.className = 'fas fa-ellipsis-v icon';`` in your case would achieve the same result.